# How do you interpret the expression עול בחיקו?

Tags: words, quotations

This is a metaphor used sometimes, such as in ואם הנהגה של רשע תהיה **עול בחיקו** של הצדיק למטה (R' Natan Nata Spira, 1585-1633, Megaleh Amukot al Iyov 34). I also read this expression in the R' Salman Eliyahu's Kerem Shlomo, Sha’ar Alef, Anaf Alef, as שאם לא תאמר ששורש הדין היה שם יהיה **עול בחיקו** יתברך שאינו נקרא שלם תכלית השלימות אלא מי שלא חסר לו שום דבר. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? I believe it means something like a load in his bosom. Perhaps a metaphor to something like a burden to his lot.

Comment: It does translate to a metaphorical "burden": "yoke in His lap". Thank you.